# I don't know how to make that box display horizontally

Tags: jquery, html, css

I tried several times to make this box which has img,h1,p tags to display  horizontally I've set the width to 30% to make it responsive but it didn't work

here's my code:

```css
/* BOXES */

#boxes {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#boxes .box {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

#boxes .box img {
  width: 90px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="boxes">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="box">
        <img src="./img/logo_html.png" alt="Html5">
        <h3>HTML5 Markup</h3>
        <p> blah blah </p>
        <img src="./img/logo_css.png" alt="Css3">
        <h3>Styling CSS</h3>
        <p>blah blah </p>
        <img src="./img/logo_brush.png" alt="Graphic Design">
        <h3>Graphic Design</h3>
        <p>blah blah </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have one box div - you need to wrap each set of elements in it's own box.  Also instead of using float (css has moved on from the need to float as it wasn't actually made for what it is being abused for), I would use flex-box:

```css
/* BOXES */

#boxes {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#boxes .container {
  display:flex;                   /* make the container flex */
  flex-direction:row;             /* align the children in a row */
  justify-content:space-between;  /* space them out equally */
}

#boxes .box {                     /* remove the float from this */
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

#boxes .box img {
  width: 90px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="boxes">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="box">
        <img src="./img/logo_html.png" alt="Html5">
        <h3>HTML5 Markup</h3>
        <p> blah blah </p>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <img src="./img/logo_css.png" alt="Css3">
        <h3>Styling CSS</h3>
        <p>blah blah </p>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <img src="./img/logo_brush.png" alt="Graphic Design">
        <h3>Graphic Design</h3>
        <p>blah blah </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[More information about flexbox (css tricks)](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

[MDN Basic concepts of Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)